# How to install elementary on a Pentium M laptop without PAE and USB boot?

Tags: system-installation

I have a Cybermaxx/Medion MD95132 laptop with a Pentium M Dothan processor (Centrino platform). When I try to install Elementery 32bits the installer says I have to use the parameter 'forcepae'.

How can I add this?

There are some workarounds by creating a bootable USB stick.
See:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/grub-n-iso
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE (it says Dotha supports PAE but
  my experience is otherwise)

Unfortunately my laptop won't boot from USB.
How can I install elementary on my laptop?

Comment: What made you install the 32bit over 64bit? Generally, asking for PAE would be a sign you should be using 64bit.

Comment: When I try to install the 64-bit version it says my CPU doesn't support 64-bit, so this is not an option.

Comment: The steps described in your second link for Ubuntu should work on the elementary installer. Unfortunately, I am not otherwise familiar with this issue.

Comment: Other Linux distributions, for instance Vector linux, gives the option to add extra parameters. How can I add the parameter forcepae in the elementary installer?

Comment: Boot your installation media, and when you see the two small, white icons at the bottom of the screen, push any key. This should get you to the elementary equivalent of this screen, where you can then follow identical steps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=forcepae-vivid.png